# HTTPヘッダに書かれた Val1="test", Val2="aaa",... といった文字列をパースしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grape

Rails4 + Grape で開発を進めています。

下記のようなヘッダ情報を上手くパースする方法はありますでしょうか。

```
X-Hoge-Authorization: Val1="test", Val2="aaa", Val3=1234
```

headers['X-Hoge-Authorization']で、中身自体は取得できるのですが、
当然ただの「Val1="test", Val2="aaa", Val3=1234」というStringになっています。
それをさらに

```
{
  Val1: "test",
  Val2: "aaa",
  Val3: 1234
}
```

という感じにパースするには自分で正規表現等を書くしかないのでしょうか。
パーサーなどが用意されているようでしたら教えて頂ければと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

なさそうなので、簡単に書いてみました。

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def parser(s)
  Hash[ s.split(/\s*,\s*/).map { |e| e.split(/\s*=\s*/) } ]
end

p parser('Val1="test", Val2="aaa", Val3 = 1234')
```

こんな感じでどうでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！やはり正規表現を書くしかなさそうだ・・・というところでした。こんなに綺麗に書けてしまうものなのですね。とても参考になりました。

Comment: @ika 綺麗かもしれませんが、文字列内に "," が含められないなど幾らか問題もあります。簡易だと割りきって使うかちゃんとした実装を作った方が良いです。

Comment: @mattn はい、参考にさせて頂きつつ、自分の実装に合うように修正させて頂きました！

Answer (score 2):

非標準のHTTPヘッダのフォーマットは上位プロトコルが任意に定めるものなので、汎用的なパーサなどというものは存在し得ません。逆に言えば、そのヘッダを定めているプロトコルを処理するライブラリであればパーサを必ず持っているはずです。

質問ではプロトコルが伏せられているため具体的には指摘できませんが、そのプロトコルを処理するライブラリを探してください。

なおパーサを自力で実装する場合は、必ず仕様を確認しましょう。識別子の文字種や、文字列中の`"`や`,`は許容されるのか、許容される場合どのようにエスケープされるのか、エンコーディングはどうなっているのか、など確認しておかないと、簡単な正規表現で実装出来ると思っていたら思わぬデータが来たときに破綻します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。パーサは基本的にないのですね。今回はフォーマットが決まっているヘッダのパースなので、あまり複雑でない正規表現で問題ありませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

質問文で書かれているとおり、keyをシンボルに、valueは文字列と数値で型を分ける、という形でアウトプットするなら、こういう書き方もできます。

```
s = 'Val1="test", Val2="aaa", Val3=1234'
s.scan(/(\w+)=("[^"]*"|\d+)/)
  .map{|k,v| [k.to_sym, v[/(?<=^")(.*)(?="$)/] || v.to_i]}
  .to_h
# => {:Val1=>"test", :Val2=>"aaa", :Val3=>1234}
```

ただこれ以外の入力パターン（例: Val4=1.23, Val-5="12\"34" など）があった場合はさらに工夫が必要になると思います。
以上、ご参考までに。

Comment: `"[^"]*"` は最短マッチじゃないので2つ以上あるとうまく行かない気がします。試してないですが。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。とりあえず回答では「Val1="test", Val2="aaa", Val3=1234」がパースできることに限定しました。それ以外のパターンは考え出すとキリがないのであえて考慮していません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！今回はフォーマットが決まっているヘッダのパースなので、あまり複雑でない正規表現で問題ありませんでした。教えて頂いたコードはシンプルですがたくさん情報がつまっていて参考になりました。

Answer (score 1):

指摘ばかりだと面白くないので僕も書いてみました。トークンのパースは JSON に頼りました。なのでバックスラッシュによるエスケープも可能ですし、浮動小数点のパースも可能です。

```
require 'json'

def parse(line)
  mx = /^\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*([0-9.]+|"(?:\\.|[^"]+)*?")\s*,?\s*/
  mv = {}
  l = line
  until l.empty? do
    m = l.match(mx)
    unless m
      raise "parse error at pos #{line.length - l.length}"
    end
    mv[m[1]] = JSON.parse("{\"dummy\": #{m[2]}}")["dummy"]
    l = l[m[0].length..-1]
  end
  mv
end

p parse('Val1="te\nst", Val2="aaa", Val3 = 1234.5')
# {"Val1"=>"te\nst", "Val2"=>"aaa", "Val3"=>1234.5}
```

仕様として必要ないのであれば文字列は両端の `"` を削るだけでいいです。ただしその場合、JSON を使わないので浮動小数点のサポートが無くなります。(作れば出来ますが)
※JSON を使うなら少し弄れば true/false のパースも出来るかと思います。
尚、トークンの解析に失敗した場合は例外が発生する様にしてあります。
以下は JSON を使わないバージョンです。

```
def parse(line)
  mx = /^\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*([0-9.]+|"(?:\\.|[^"]+)*?")\s*,?\s*/
  mv = {}
  l = line
  until l.empty? do
    m = l.match(mx)
    unless m
      raise "parse error at pos #{line.length - l.length}"
    end
    mv[m[1]] = m[2][0] == '"' ? m[2][1..-2] : m[2].to_i
    l = l[m[0].length..-1]
  end
  mv
end

p parse('Val1="test", Val2="aaa", Val3 = 1234')
# {"Val1"=>"test", "Val2"=>"aaa", "Val3"=>1234}
```

Comment: とても詳細なコードをありがとうございます！jsonに任せる方法もあるのですね。とても参考になりました。